# Contingency coefficient using for loop in R

Tags: r

Consider the following data set (named `data`).

```
library(DescTools)
v1 v2 v3 w1 w2 w3
 1  0  0  0  1  0
 0  1  0  0  0  1
 0  0  1  1  0  0 
 1  0  0  0  1  0
 0  1  0  0  0  1
 0  0  1  1  0  0
```

My objective is to compute contingency coefficient for all combination of `(v1,v2,v3)` and `(w1,w2,w3)`. To make it clear, `v1 & w1`,`v1 & w2`, `v1 & w3`, etc using for loop. For example, the loop will do the following at the first iteration.

```
tab1 <- table(data$v1,data$w1)
c1 < ContCoef(tab1)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results = list()
for (v_col in c("v1", "v2", "v3")) {
  for(w_col in c("w1", "w2", "w3")) {
    tab = table(data[[v_col]], data[[w_col]])
    results[[paste(v_col, w_col)]] = ContCoef(tab)
  }
}

# view individual results
results[["v1_w2"]]
results[["v3_w1"]]
```